# R multiple case_when conditions and for loops

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, case

I'm trying to solve a complex problem, where I need to check conditions in 3 different data.frames to mutate the values in the main data frame.
I don't know if there is a smarter way, but I definitely need help from a experienced coder.

This is my code until now:

```r
##Check on which machine the first material number with the longest runtime is still being produced
##Machine that is already full (var_ApFull) is filtered out

      for(j in 1:nrow(df_MatAlternativ)){
        
        df_AlternMA <- df_ABC3 %>% 
          filter(Matnr == df_MatAlternativ$Matnr[j],
                 Arbeitsplatz != var_ApVoll) %>% 
          distinct()
        
        ##sort ascending
        df_AlternMA <-df_AlternMA %>% 
          arrange(`Total.Machine.Time.(Hr.)`)
        
        ##Check whether the alternative machine still has capacity
        for(l in 1:nrow(df_AlternMA)){
          
          df_KapaVerschiebung <- df_geringsteLZ2 %>% 
            filter(Arbeitsplatz==df_AlternMA$Arbeitsplatz[l])
          
          ##If capacity on alternative machine available, then subtract TotMachineTime of this material number from workstation in df_geringestLZ2

          case_when(df_KapaVerschiebung$Machine_Capacity + df_AlternMA$`Total.Machine.Time.(Hr.)`[l] <= 5700 ~
                      
                      for(m in 1:nrow(df_geringsteEinzeln)){
                        
                        df_geringsteLZEinzeln2 <- df_geringsteLZEinzeln %>% 
                          dplyr::mutate(Arbeitsplatz = 
                                          case_when(Matnr[m] == df_MatAlternativ$Matnr[j] ~ 
                                                      df_AlternMA$Arbeitsplatz[l], 
                                                    TRUE~
                                          )
                          ) 
                        
                        ##Change Maschine Capacity oh alternative machine

                        df_geringsteLZEinzeln2 <- df_geringsteLZEinzeln2 %>% 
                          dplyr::mutate(Machine_Capacity_Total = 
                                          case_when(Matnr[m] == df_MatAlternativ$Matnr[j] ~ 
                                                      df_AlternMA$`Total.Machine.Time.(Hr.)`[l], 
                                                    TRUE~
                                          )
                          )
                        
                        ##Change Maschine Capacity of old machine
                        var_MaCapa <- df_geringsteLZEinzeln %>% 
                          filter(Matnr==df_MatAlternativ[j]) %>% 
                          select(Machine_Capacity_Total),
                        
                        df_geringsteLZEinzeln2 <- df_geringsteLZEinzeln2 %>% 
                          dplyr::mutate(Machine_Capacity_Total=case_when(Matnr[m]!=df_MatAlternativ$Matnr[j] ~
                                                                           (Machine_Capacity_Total-var_MaCapa)
                          )
                          )
                        
                       
                      }
                    
                    ,TRUE~
                      
          )
          
        }
      }
    }
}
```

I can't test this, because of these errors:

[image]

But I don't see any missing brackets in the code.

Comment: It is unclear if you could do the inner most for-loop.

Comment: Consider `join` on all tables and then run `mutate` without nested looping through rows. I wish I could show but many data frames beyond 3 are used here and your non-English names are not too clear!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the beginning is missing:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df_geringsteLZ2)){
```

df_geringsteLZ2 %>%

```
while(Machine_Capacity[i]>=5700){
  var_ApVoll <- Arbeitsplatz[i]
  
  ##Get alle Matnr, die auf Maschine laufen, deren Capacity>5700 (var_ApVoll)
  df_MatAlternativ <- df_geringsteLZ %>% 
    filter(Arbeitsplatz == var_ApVoll) %>% 
    arrange(desc(`Total.Machine.Time.(Hr.)`)) %>% 
    select(Matnr)
```